Need help in understanding Tangential Acceleration
I am studying Circular motion and I am confused about tangential acceleration and tangential velocity. I am studying uniform circular motion and it says the tangential acceleration is $0$ in uniform circular motion but tangential velocity isn't because the direction is changing. Can someone explain how that is so ? And also can the tangential acceleration be written as $\frac {d|v_{tangential} |} {dt}$ and centripetal acceleration as $|\frac {dv_{tangential}} {dt}|$ ?

"How is that possible?" is not a very focused question.

Here are some other questions I would vote to close:  "Grass is green.  How is that possible?".  "37 is a prime number.  How is that possible?"  "Today is Thursday.  How is that possible?"

@WillO Obviously the questioner means "can someone explain this to me ?". Are we now so elitist that we downvote and criticise questioners for a less-than-perfect command of English idiom ??

For tangential acceleration to happen- you need to apply torque, which of course breaks uniform circular motion, making it non-uniform, i.e. tangential speed is changing over time. Velocity is a vector, which at each circle point points along tangential line touching that point and so it changes as body rotates, but it's modulus- does not, i.,e. $||\vec v_{tang}||=\text{const}$.

@gandalf61 :  So would you be okay with a question of the form "Today is Thursday.  Can someone explain this to me?" ?

@gandalf61 That doesn't change the fact that the question is not focused and generic which makes it a duplicate of many other questions. Asking "why doesn't the speed change in circular motion" for the $n$th time adds nothing to the site. Specific questions that focus on a particular line of reasoning and include the asker's own understanding do. This has nothing to do with elitism or whatever else you might call it.

Derivatives speak to the instantaneous behavior at a point.  It is possible to have a 1st derivative that is non-zero and a 2nd derivative that is 0 at a point.  They're simply measuring two different things.
As a trivial example, the function $f(x)=x^2$ at zero has:

a value of zero: $f(0) = x^2 = 0^2 = 0$
a 1st derivative of zero: $\frac{df}{dt}_{x=0}=2x = 2(0) = 0$
a non-zero 2nd derivative: $\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}_{x=0}=2$

In the case of circular motion, there is a non-zero velocity and there is a non-zero acceleration.  However, if we choose to phrase those vectors in terms of tangental and radial directions, we find that the velocity is 100% in the tangental direction, and acceleration is 100% in the radial direction.
The pattern we see in uniform circular motion is common.  Emphasis on "uniform."  Were there to be an acceleration in the tangential direction, it would be gaining speed.  Were there to be no velocity in the tangential direction, it would not be moving.  In these situations with constant speed, you will find the acceleration is always at right angles to the motion.

Thank you also can you help me with the the tangential acceleration be written as d|v tangential | / dt and centripetal acceleration as |dv tangential / dt|

The easiest way I know of to do is is to plot the path in x and y (I e. r cos(theta) and sin(theta)).  Take the derivatives and you'll get a velocity and then acceleration vectors that point in the right direction.  Then just convert from x and y to tangential and radial
